# Are the any options for interfacing with the command prompt process from a .NET application other than the standard IO?

Tags: .net, powershell, f#, command-prompt

Yesterday I figured out that one can [control the command line process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745894/how-to-add-a-local-environment-to-a-process-in-net) by redirecting the standard input and writing to it, but now I have a problem that unlike when launching a process directly, if I call the Nvidia NVCC compiler via the command prompt, I do not get any direct reply whether the compilation was successful.

Rather, the F# app I am controlling the command prompt from only sees text and I won't even get a reply for when compilation is done unless I build a parser for the output stream or something to that effect.

The least labor intensive way of getting what I want seems to be using [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to notify me when the `.ptx` file is created so I can load it into the program then, but I do not know much about the command prompt, so I thought to ask here whether there are any better solutions than this.

It would be great if I could do something like pass a callback into it instead. Maybe instead of using the standard Ms-Dos prompt, the newer Windows Powershell has some better interfacing features?

Comment: nvcc returns values, it should be 0 when compiled. You can capture, using Process.ExitCode(). But you are right, this compiler have some problems, cmake noticed too https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html

Comment: That is what I could get if I started the process directly using the Process class, but what I am doing here is starting the command prompt and then using the redirected standard input, running the compiler from the command prompt instead. The reason why I am doing that in such a roundabout fashion is because `cl` on which `nvcc` depends on needs to run `vcvarsx86_amd64.bat` to pull in all the include and library directories. If not for that I would call `nvcc` directly instead.

Comment: You have some options better, than run cmd as FileName. 1) combine 2 calls in own bat file and specify this file in StartupInfo as executable and obtain return value of last command (compiler) 2)specify all environment variable set in vcvars in EnvironmentVariables field of your StartupInfo and command  line arguments of compiler in Arguments field of StartupInfo   and just use nvcc as FileName 
In both cases you not need to redirect in/out and parse something, you just call WaitForExit() and obtain ExitCode

Comment: The second option would be too hard because the `vcvars` file is considerable. The first option did occur to me, but I was not sure whether the return would be based on the last call, so I went with the flow and decided to use the FileSystemWatcher, but that idea might be worth trying out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may be of interest, I decided to go with vitalygolub's idea for my neural net library. Here is how it looks like:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.IO

let compile_kernel_using_nvcc_bat_router kernel_code kernel_name =
    let nvcc_router_path = Path.Combine(kernels_dir,"nvcc_router.bat")
    use p = 
        let procStartInfo = 
            ProcessStartInfo(
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = nvcc_router_path)

        let outputHandler f (_sender:obj) (args:DataReceivedEventArgs) = f args.Data
        let p = new Process(StartInfo = procStartInfo)
        let print_to_standard_output = outputHandler <| fun x -> printfn "%s" x
        //p.OutputDataReceived.AddHandler(DataReceivedEventHandler (print_to_standard_output))
        p.ErrorDataReceived.AddHandler(DataReceivedEventHandler (print_to_standard_output))
        p

    let quote x = sprintf "\"%s\"" x
    let call x = sprintf "call %s" x
    let quoted_vs_path_to_vcvars = Path.Combine(visual_studio_path, @"VC\bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat") |> quote
    let quoted_vs_path_to_cl = Path.Combine(visual_studio_path, @"VC\bin\x86_amd64") |> quote
    let quoted_cuda_toolkit_path_to_include = Path.Combine(cuda_toolkit_path,"include") |> quote
    let quoted_kernels_dir = kernels_dir |> quote
    let target_path = Path.Combine(kernels_dir,kernel_name+".ptx")
    let quoted_target_path = target_path |> quote
    let input_path = Path.Combine(kernels_dir,"_temp.cu")
    let quoted_input_path = input_path |> quote

    File.WriteAllText(input_path,kernel_code)

    let _ = 
        use nvcc_router_file = File.OpenWrite(nvcc_router_path)
        use nvcc_router_stream = new StreamWriter(nvcc_router_file)

        nvcc_router_stream.WriteLine(call quoted_vs_path_to_vcvars)
        nvcc_router_stream.WriteLine(
            sprintf 
                """nvcc -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -ccbin %s  -I%s --keep-dir %s -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 -ptx -cudart static  -o %s %s"""
                quoted_vs_path_to_cl quoted_cuda_toolkit_path_to_include quoted_kernels_dir quoted_target_path quoted_input_path)

    if p.Start() = false then failwith "NVCC failed to run."
    p.BeginOutputReadLine()
    p.BeginErrorReadLine()
    p.WaitForExit()

    if p.ExitCode <> 0 then failwithf "NVCC failed compilation with code %i" p.ExitCode

    cuda_context.LoadKernelPTX(target_path,kernel_name)
```

Calling `.bat` files from a `.bat` file requires using the `call` command for legacy reasons. Apart from that it works quite well and terminates with error codes other than zero when compilation fails and outputs the error to the error stream. The input stream handler is commented out on purpose.

Comment: Powershell uses multiple streams that can pass typed objects, not just text. `cmd` is a legacy command prompt anyway

Comment: I was surprised to find out yesterday that Powershell can construct .NET objects. What are these streams you just mentioned?

Comment: Check [Welcome to the Powershell Information Stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/07/04/weekend-scripter-welcome-to-the-powershell-information-stream/). You get Host (Console), Error, Warning, Verbose,Information, Debug *and* Progress. You can writhe to them with Write-Host, Write-Progress etc.  Chekc [about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) for ways to redirect streams.